# Correct redirect after log in | ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

When user requests a page that is only for authenticated users he/she is redirected to login page. I also use authorization based on user role in my nested web.config.

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Former solution to this was if user is authenticated redirect him to the page he/she requested, but because user could request a page he/she was not authorized to see website kept returning him to login page over and over.

```
if (_user != null)
{           
    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = _user.Id;
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(_user.Id.ToString(), false);
}
```

I do not like this so I did change the code to use Response.Redirect() to route user to his/her login page. Unfortunately I did not realized user can't reach the page he/she requested in the first place and always ends up on "welcome page".

```
if (_user != null)
{             
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = _user.Id;

            var role = _userAuth.GetUserRole(_user.Id); //Gets correct role for a user

            if (role == "admin")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/adm/Default.aspx");   
            }
            else if (role == "service")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/service/Default.aspx");                  
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/user/Welcome.aspx");                  
            }
}
```

Is there a way how to route the user to the page he/she requested in case he/she is authenticated and authorized and route him/her to page saying "You are not authorized to see this" otherwise?

Comment: If you're using Principal and/or Identity, you can check the Request.IsAuthenticated property to see if the User previously authenticated.

Comment: If the user is already authenticated (Request.IsAuthenticated) you may want to access the Request.Url to apply your authorization check to decide whether they should visit the page or defaults to default.aspx based on the role

Comment: I might not get this right but I don't know how this could help me.
When I am not logged in and try to reach site.com/contact I would like to be diverted to site.com/login and after successful login I want to be redirected to site.com/contact. 
Instead I got site.com/contact > site.com/login > site.com/welcome from where I am supposed to click my way to contact page.